# CSS only showing in Firefox, not others

Tags: php, html, css, cross-browser

I have been working on my site and now I'm doing some browser compatibility checks and something weird is going with the CSS of one link.

I have a css class applied and some php codes to execute for Firefox, but in any other browsers the style doesn't show and the php doesn't execute. I don't have an idea what's going on.

I would appreciate if someone could take a look and help me fix it.

This is page the page that is giving me trouble ([**www.savingsulove.com/by-location/**](http://www.savingsulove.com/by-location/)). If you view it in Firefox, you will see that there is a middle section that is supposed to automatically display (I used an if statement and css). It works in Firefox but not in other browsers.

Please help

Comment: I don't see any difference between Firefox and Safari. Btw, the HTML produced by your PHP script will always be the same, whatever browser you're using.

Comment: What is the problem? Search fields in the middle only appear when the link is clicked. I get this same behaviour in FireFox, IE9 and Chrome.

Comment: I get identical behaviour in Firefox and IE8.

Comment: Well, everyone gets **identical behaviour**.

Comment: I see things identical as well (chrome and FF on Ubuntu 64).  Do you really want us to try IE ;-)

Comment: @gdinari: Could you please post the PHP code and/or a screen shot of what the site should look like when it's functioning as you expect it to?

Comment: Open up your page and turn on firebug or Chrome's js debugger. You should see some errors that need fixing. If you're using Chrome, turn on resource tracking. There's a dangling `</link>` tag generated by a script.

Comment: @gdinari: Partially related... I suggest you take a gander at http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.savingsulove.com%2Fby-location%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 (W3C validator)

Comment: @Capsule,@GolezTrol,@thirtydot,@Alain: Yes the link behaves properly, it opens the search field when clicked, but it doesn't automatically open in the other browsers. It only works in firefox, when the page loads that search field is automatically show and I don't have to click the link. In the other browsers the link doesn't even show properly. It has a blue color, which is default for my links, but I added a css class to it to style, but in the other browsers it doesn't apply the style as it does in firefox.

Comment: @nmichaels, I will definitely try the debugger. Hopefully it will help. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @stealthyninja: Yes, Im using the validator now. Ive been designing and paying attention to functionality. Now I checking for syntax and other errors. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your cache in the other browsers.  It is possible that you visited your site before you got it working and you are getting that cached version in your other browsers.

The PHP will be executed the same no matter which browser you are using (unless you specifically tell it not to).

Comment: Yes the php works as it's supposed to in all the browsers, but the problem is the css is not applied in the other browsers except firefox. I cleared my cache (always do), but that didn't help. I'll try running some debugging with firebug. Thanks for the advice. I appreciate it.